# Composer running with SSL/TLS protection disabled

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, backend, laravel-10

I want to run this commande but nothing worfk `composer require laravel/ui` or any Composer they don't work
this is the output

```
PS C:\Users\moham\OneDrive\Bureau\ffff> composer create-project laravel/ui
Creating a "bagisto/bagisto" project at "./bagisto"
You are running Composer with SSL/TLS protection disabled.

In RemoteFilesystem.php line 476:
                                                                                                                                           
  The "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: no valid certs found cafile stream: `C:\PHP\extras\ssl\ca   
  cert.pem'                                                                                                                                
  Failed to enable crypto                                                                                                                  
  Failed to open stream: operation failed
```

[You are running Composer with SSL/TLS protection disabled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaT5I.png)

I saw somme people say that I must change from
`;extension=php_openssl.dll`
TO
`extension=php_openssl.dll`
I did it but the same result

How I cant work with comper without this errors?